# MySQL view of just one column?

Tags: mysql, view

Can a *regular* table (not created by a view) contain a single column which is a view of a column from another table, or does a view always have to create a separate *virtual table?*

If yes, what code (simple example) would be used to add the virtual column?

Comment: What's wrong with views? You can add a trigger to the another table and update the view like regular table you created. But you'd need an id column for that too (security-wise).

Comment: What's wrong with views? = Normally nothing; In this case I need one column added to a table and need to know if a view of a single column could be used, thanks.

Comment: Caveat: views are only updatable if they are merged into your query; this will be the case if they were defined with `ALGORITHM = MERGE` or (so long as MySQL is able to do so) if `ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED` (the default if not specified).  It will **not** be the case if `ALGORITHM = TEMPTABLE`.  See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-algorithms.html) for more info.